# how does hexadecimal color and RGB color work

Tags: html, css, hex, rgb

How can i know what combination of color produce certain color in RGB hex?

For example, black `#000000` in hex and `RGB(0, 0, 0)`. red is `##FF0000 in hex and`RGB(255,0,0)`.

Comment: Plz help.I am studying html from edx and i confused in this part.Do i need to know something to understand this part

Answer (score 3):

In hex, the colour is coded as `#RRGGBB`, where each pair of digits `RR`, `GG` or `BB` represents the intensity of red, green or blue respectively as a hexadecimal value between 00 and FF (0 and 255 in decimal).  You can also write `rgb(RRR, GGG, BBB)` to mean the same thing, where the `RRR`, `GGG`, and `BBB`are decimal numbers.

For each number, 0 means black, and 255 (or FF) means full intensity.

In hex, you can also use three digits: `#123` means the same as `#112233`.

Although you might be able to work out in your head what sort of colour a particular mix of red, green and blue might give you, it's probably easier to use a colour chart.  See https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hex+colour+chart for some examples.

In CSS, you can also use keywords like `orange` to represent common colours - these are much easier to remember.

For more info, see [Applying color to HTML elements using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Applying_color#How_to_describe_a_color).

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better you use a conversor, like this:
https://www.webpagefx.com/web-design/hex-to-rgb/

Comment: Thz for ur help but what i want to know is how things work in hex color code and rgb colo rcode

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it closely, you'll notice that the hex of `RGB(r, g, b)` is just the three values individually converted to base 16 and joined together, prepending with a '#'.

As an example, let's check out red.

In RGB, red is defined as `RGB(255, 0, 0)`. To convert this to hexcode, we just need to get the first number of the RGB first. In our case, that is `255`. The hex of `255` is `FF`. So, `"FF"` would be the first color in our hexcode.

The remaining colours green and blue both have a value of 0. Converting those two to hex would give us `00`. We append both `00`s to the hexcode, and we will get `FF0000`. That is the hexcode of red!

Notice a pattern in hexcodes and `rgb()`? The first two numbers refers to the red value, the second two refers to the green value, and the last two refers to the blue value.

[image: RGB matching with hexcode]

Just like what JRI [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50307958/1116098), `#RRGGBB` or in rgb, `RGB(RRR, GGG, BBB)`.

The values of red, green, and blue can range from 0 to 255. The combination of the three will give you a maximum of 16,777,216 colours to choose from. So how do you choose the colour?

It's going to be difficult to find the right balance of colours in your head. The higher the value of red is compared to the rest, the more red the colour will be. The higher the value of green is compared to the other colours, the more green it will be, and vice-versa.

You could think of red as providing the darkness of the overall colour; the blue providing the lightness of the colour; and the green providing a good middle ground.

As much as possible, use a colour chart or use the colour picker from an app or website to make things easier.